# Change kubernetes master env variable on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to enable Stackdriver logging with my Kubernetes cluster on GKE.

It's stated here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/logging/stackdriver/

> This article assumes that you have created a Kubernetes cluster with cluster-level logging support for sending logs to Stackdriver Logging. You can do this either by selecting the Enable Stackdriver Logging checkbox in the create cluster dialogue in GKE, or by setting the `KUBE_LOGGING_DESTINATION` flag to gcp when manually starting a cluster using `kube-up.sh`.

But my cluster was created without this option enabled.

How do I change the environment variable while my cluster is running?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, logging isn't a setting that can be enabled/disabled on a cluster once it is running. This is something that we hope to change in the near future, but in the mean time your best bet is to delete and recreate your cluster (sorry!).

Comment: Do you have any updates on this? I don't like the idea of re-creating the cluster very much (smells like a lot of error prone steps) and I fear that getting rid of the stackdriver components in 1.7 is not as easy as it was with 1.5.

Comment: You can now enable/disable logging on a running cluster -- see https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters/logging.