# GKE - Stackdriver

Tags: logging, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

I am trying to get the output of my pod logs into Stackdriver, but I am running into an issue where they are not being sent to Stackdriver.

If I look at the GKE cluster details, it is showing this:

```
Stackdriver Logging - Disabled
Stackdriver Monitoring  - Enabled
```

I cannot find any information on how to enable Stackdriver on a running cluster.

There is a running heapster pod, and I have run this command as this wasn't set:

```
gcloud container clusters update <cluster> --monitoring-service=monitoring.googleapis.com
```

That is now showing the correct service, but this doesn't solve the logging issue. Is anyone able to shed any light on how to enable to logging?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Currently there is no support for enabling logging in GKE cluster after it's been created. We are aware of the problem and we're going to introduce such possibility.

In the meantime you can try the following workarounds:

- Create fluentd DaemonSet on your own using [fluentd-gcp-ds.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-gcp/fluentd-gcp-ds.yaml). You need to change namespace there to avoid interaction with [addon-manager](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/addon-manager). The disadvantage of this approach is that GKE won't manage/upgrade your fluentd DaemonSet.
- Migrate to a new cluster with logging disabled if this works for your.

Please let me know if you have more questions. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hi DavidO is there a way with GKE to use Elasticsearch/Kibana, from what I've read that seems to be the option for AWS but wondering if it's easy to swap on GKE.

Comment: Do you have any updates on this? I don't like the idea of re-creating the cluster very much (smells like a lot of error prone steps) and I fear that getting rid of the stackdriver components in 1.7 is not as easy as it was with 1.5.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the Strackdriver api enabled in your project?

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/logging.googleapis.com/overview

I don't see an option anywhere to specifically enable Stackdriver logging after you've already created the cluster. When you create a new cluster the option is on by default, so I guess recreating it is one option.

Comment: Actually, recreating seems to be your only option at the moment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41810624/188947

Comment: Yer I did think recreating was the option. I have stackdriver enabled I can view metrics for the cluster just not seeing any logs. Not sure why it wouldn't of been enabled when the cluster was creating, I see you have to manually disable it and I don't recall disabling it.

Comment: Stackdriver logging was still in beta a while ago so maybe it wasn't enabled by default when you created your cluster the first time.

Comment: Do you know when they changed it? I think my cluster is only about 2-3 weeks old. What a pain. Damn means re-creating the setup.